# create scala dataframe out of custom object

Tags: scala, object, dataframe, nested

I am a newbie in scala. I will try to be as clear as possible.I have the following code:

```
case class Session (bf: Array[File]) 
case class File(s: s, a: Option[a], b: Option[b], c: Option[c])

case class s(s1:Int, s2:String) 
case class a(a1:Int, a2:String) 
case class b(b1:Int, b2:String)  
case class c(c1:Int, c2:String)


val x = Session(...) // some values here, many session objects grouped in a  dataset collection i.e. Dataset[Sessions]
```

1. I want to know how to create dataframes from a Dataset[Sessions]. I do not 
   know how to manipulate such a complex structure.
2. how to create a dataframe from Dataset[sessions] only containing the custom
   object "a".

Thank you

Comment: What is a dataframe in this context? Which library are you referring to?

Comment: spark class called dataframe https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Spark `DataSet` works much like a regular Scala collection. It has a `toDF()` operation to create a `DataFrame` out of it. Now you just need to extract the right data out of it using different transformations.

1. `flatMap` it into a `DataSet` of `File`
2. `filter` every `File` for a non-empty `a`
3. `map` every remaining `File` to `a`
4. call `toDF()` to create a `DataFrame`

In code this would be:

```
val ds: DataSet[Session] = ...
ds.flatMap(_.bf)
  .filter(_.a.isDefined)
  .map(_.a.get)
  .toDF()
```

In Scala you can also combine the `filter` and `map` to a `collect`, which would lead to the following code:

```
ds.flatMap(_.bf).collect({ case File(_, Some(a), _, _) => a }).toDF()
```